# Why does a more general type affect runtime in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, ghc

Consider the two following implementations of an infinite Fibonacci sequence:

```
fibsA :: Num a => [a]
fibsA = 0:1:(zipWith (+) fibsA (tail fibsA))

fibsB :: [Integer]
fibsB = 0:1:(zipWith (+) fibsB (tail fibsB))
```

In GHCI, executing `fibsB !! k` is much faster than executing `fibsA !! k`.
In particular, it seems that the values of `fibsA` are continuously recalculated (not memoized/stored).

Furthermore, when the type signature is omitted, GHCI's `:t` shows it to be `[Integer]`, and the function performs accordingly.

This behavior also occurs in compiled code (`ghc -O3 Fibs.hs`).

Why is it the case that `Integer` is so much faster than `Num a => a`?

Comment: The answer is the same as the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25958007/why-ghc-changes-the-evaluation-way-due-to-the-optimisation-flag/25960838 even if the question isn't an exact duplicate.

Comment: @Carl Nice find, thanks! I didn't see that in the related questions list.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you write `fibsA :: Num a => [a]`, the compiler constructs what is essentially

```
fibsA :: NumDict a -> [a]
```

Where

```
data NumDict a = NumDict
    { (+)         :: a -> a -> a
    , (-)         :: a -> a -> a
    , (*)         :: a -> a -> a
    , negate      :: a -> a
    , abs         :: a -> a
    , signum      :: a -> a
    , fromInteger :: Integer -> a
    }
```

Notice that `Num a` has moved from being a constraint to being an argument to the function.  [A typeclass is essentially just a lookup table for each type that implements the class](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/MDCC-TechTalk-Classes-Jim-but-not-as-we-know-them).  So for `Num`, you'd have by default

```
mkInteger_NumDict :: NumDict Integer
mkInteger_NumDict = NumDict
    { (+) = integer_plus
    , (-) = integer_minus
    , (*) = integer_mult
    , ...
    }

mkInt_NumDict     :: NumDict Int

mkFloat_NumDict   :: NumDict Float

mkDouble_NumDict  :: NumDict Double
```

and these get automatically passed to a function using a typeclass when the instance is resolved.  This means that our function `fibsA` essentially takes an argument.  When you call it from GHCi, the defaulting rules kick in and pick `Integer`, but since it's being called this way it would look more like this internally:

```
{-# RecordWildCards #-}  -- To reduce typing

fibsA :: NumDict a -> [a]
fibsA nd@(NumDict{..}) = fromInteger 0 : fromInteger 1 : zipWith (+) (fibsA nd) (tail $ fibsA nd)
```

Do you see the problem with this?  It's still recursive, but now it has to make a function call each step of the way, reducing performance.  If you wanted to make it really fast, a smart programmer would do

```
fibsA nd@(NumDict{..}) = fromInteger 0 : fromInteger 1 : zipWith (+) fibsA' (tail fibsA')
    where fibsA' = fibsA nd
```

This at least allows memoization.  However, a haskell binary can't really perform this optimization at runtime, that happens at compile time.  So what you end up with is a slower recursive function.  With `fibsB`, you're specifying the type concretely, there are no polymorphic constraints on it's type signature.  The value `fibsB` has no implicit or explicit arguments, so when referred to it's a pointer to the same object in memory.  `fibsA` is a pointer to a function, so when used recursively it returns new objects in memory, and has no memoization.  This is why `fibsB` is faster than `fibsA`, only `fibsB` gets optimized because the compiler doesn't have to make it work for all `Num`, only `Integer`.

Comment: Great explanation! That video was really interesting.

Comment: @WChargin I've watched it a couple times, SPJ does a great job of explaining just how simple typeclasses are and I feel that understanding how they're implemented makes them make a lot more sense.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to @bheklilr's thorough explanation: You can also make `fibsA` fast, if you perform the list sharing inside the function, making it non-recursive (hiding the recursion inside):

```
fibsA' :: Num a => [a]
fibsA' = 
  let f = 0:1:(zipWith (+) f (tail f))
  in f
```